# PostScript-equivalent to exit(EXIT_FAILURE) - How to exit PostScript with a non-zero exit value?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I know the PostScript equivalent to `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`, it is the `quit` operator. However, the `quit` operator does not take any arguments, it's just `quit`, and not `0 quit` or `1 quit`.

I'm looking for the PostScript equivalent to `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`. If necessary, it can be assumed that the PostScript interpreter is GhostScript.

It can furthermore be assumed that the normally discouraged behavior of `quit` of terminating the PostScript interpreter is not just accepted but even desired in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that appears to work with simple command line testing.

```
$ gsnd -q -c 'errordict/handleerror{stop}put (theres-no-file-with-this-name)run'
GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
$ echo $?
1
```

Calling `run` triggers the `invalidfileaccess` error requested by `-dSAFER` hidden in the `gsnd` script. Replacing `errordict/handleerror` suppresses the printing of the long error report.